# Native release error on MonoMac, possibly related to events

Tags: c#, macos, memory-leaks, mono, monomac

MonoMac seems to be leaking objects under events, my logs show:

```
[NativeRelease ERROR]: type: MonoMac.Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher handle: 6437120 count: 2 gchandle: 0
[NativeRelease ERROR]: type: MonoMac.Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher handle: 27194624 count: 2 gchandle: 0
[NativeRelease ERROR]: type: MonoMac.Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher handle: 47428288 count: 2 gchandle: 0
```

But that doesn't tell me much about what was leaked. Anyone has any idea on how I could figure out what objects are leaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a harmless message, see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6045 for more information.